# Stop Embedded Youtube Video Iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, youtube

My code is not working with this youtube url. How to stop this iframe video?

```
<iframe class="youtube-video1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6VuiyCbZwhw?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer" width="853" height="461"></iframe>
<script>
  $('.stop-video').click(function() {

    $('.youtube-video1')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'pauseVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It is working fine, just add button.

Comment: What do you mean "stop"? Did you mean how to  make it not `autoplay`?

Comment: @RiteshKhandekar If you know how to do it, please add an answer.